# R code to search a word in a paragraph and copy the sentence in a variable

Tags: regex, r, parsing, substring

**Input**

Juventus striker Carlos Tevez has been  cleared to start the season with the Italian club after the former Manchester  City star.When Tevez agreed to join Juve earlier in the close season, the Argentine  still had to complete the majority of his 250 hours of unpaid work, imposed by  Macclesfield Magistrates Court as punishment for a string of driving offences  earlier this year.However, the terms have now changed, meaning Tevez will pay a fine instead  of fulfilling the order, allowing him to continue his career with Juve.District Judge Bridget Knight accepted there were circumstances beyond  Tevez control in his inability to fulfil the terms of his order, saying:"This is only a technical breach. It is not, I repeat not, a case of a  footballer thumbing his nose at a court order.It is thought Tevez legal team argued that as the former Manchester  United star was sold by City, he was not responsible in law for his inability  to comply with the order.I would like to thank the court for its understanding.

**Question**

> We Need to search a word in the above given paragraph like "Carlos" and copy the entire sentence as show below

**Output**
Juventus striker Carlos Tevez has been  cleared to start the season with the Italian club after the former Manchester  City star.

I the above output we can find the word "Carlos".
Need your help to build a r code in this case

Comment: Please post the code you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: If you have no code, take a look at `Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator` from `openNLP` and, then, if you have specific issues implementing a solution, post another question with the bits that aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using the `qdap` package:

```
x <- 'Juventus striker Carlos Tevez has been cleared to start the season with the Italian club after 
    the former Manchester City star.When Tevez agreed to join Juve earlier in the close season, the 
    Argentine still had to complete the majority of his 250 hours of unpaid work, imposed by 
    Macclesfield Magistrates Court as punishment for a string of driving offences earlier this year.
    However, the terms have now changed, meaning Tevez will pay a fine instead of fulfilling the order, 
    allowing him to continue his career with Juve.District Judge Bridget Knight accepted there were 
    circumstances beyond Tevez control in his inability to fulfil the terms of his order, saying: 
    "This is only a technical breach. It is not, I repeat not, a case of a footballer thumbing his nose 
    at a court order.It is thought Tevez legal team argued that as the former Manchester United star was 
    sold by City, he was not responsible in law for his inability to comply with the order.I would like 
    to thank the court for its understanding.'

library(qdap)

dat <- data.frame(text=sent_detect(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Search(dat, "Carlos")

## [1] "Juventus striker Carlos Tevez has been cleared to start the season with the Italian club after the former Manchester City star."
```

Comment: I really with I could install your package but `rJava` keeps giving me problems.  Hopefully I can get it to install soon, I want to use it!

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm guessing it has to do with different R and Java architectures.  I have a small snippet describing resources to get this up and running: http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/vignettes/qdap_vignette.html#java

Answer (score 1):

First I would separate the text into sentences (assuming you saved the text in a text file called `input.txt`):

```
text <- readLines("input.txt")
sentences <- strsplit(text,".",fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
```

Then I would select the sentences containing the word you are searching for, using `grep`:

```
sentences <- sentences[grep("Carlos",sentences)]

#[1] "Juventus striker Carlos Tevez has been cleared to start the season with the Italian club after the former Manchester City star"
```