# R code to search a word in a paragraph and copy preceding as well after sentences from key words

Tags: r

In RStudio I have followed the approach of [R code to search a word in a paragraph and copy the sentence in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438570/r-code-to-search-a-word-in-a-paragraph-and-copy-the-sentence-in-a-variable)

to identify the sentence which contains the key word (eg. pollination below) I require.

However, I want to extract one sentences preceeding and one sentences after this sentence containing the key word I require.

Desired output for input below:
They range much further north than honey bees, and colonies can be found on Ellesmere Island in northern Canada, only 880 km from the north pole! With the recent popularity of using bumblebees in glasshouse pollination they will probably be found in most parts of the world before long (see below), especially Bombus terrestris which seems to be the most popular species sold for this purpose.
Recently there have been proposals to introduce bumblebees into Australia to pollinate crops in glasshouses.

If there are many occurrences of word pollination, how I can obtain this through a loop function.

Here is my R code so far:

```
text <- "Bumblebees are found mainly in northern temperate regions, thoughthere are a few native South American species and New Zealand has some naturalised species that were introduced around 100 years ago to pollinate red clover. They range much further north than honey bees, and colonies can be found on Ellesmere Island in northern Canada, only 880 km from the north pole!
With the recent popularity of using bumblebees in glasshouse pollination they will probably be found in most parts of the world before long (see below), especially Bombus terrestris which seems to be the most popular species sold for this purpose. Recently there have been proposals to introduce bumblebees into Australia to pollinate crops in glasshouses. Now, though I dearly love bumblebees, I do think that this might not be a very good idea. No matter what security measures are taken, mated queens WILL escape eventually and that will probably lead to their establishment in the wild.And yet another non-native invasion of a country that has suffered more than most from such things. This invasion may or may not be benign, but isn't it better to err on the side of caution? Apparently there are already colonies of Bombus terrestris on Tasmania, so I suppose it is now only a matter of time before they reach the mainland."


#end

library(qdap)
sent_detect(text)

##There are NINE sentences in text 
##Output

[1] "Bumblebees are found mainly in northern temperate regions, though there are a few native South American species and New Zealand has some naturalised species that were introduced around 100 years ago to pollinate red clover."            
[2] "They range much further north than honey bees, and colonies can be found on Ellesmere Island in northern Canada, only 880 km from the north pole!"                                                                                          
[3] "With the recent popularity of using bumblebees in glasshouse pollination they will probably be found in most parts of the world before long, especially Bombus terrestris which seems to be the most popular species sold for this purpose."
[4] "Recently there have been proposals to introduce bumblebees into Australia to pollinate crops in glasshouses."                                                                                                                               
[5] "Now, though I dearly love bumblebees, I do think that this might not be a very good idea."                                                                                                                                                  
[6] "No matter what security measures are taken, mated queens WILL escape eventually and that will probably lead to their establishment in the wild."                                                                                            
[7] "And yet another non-native invasion of a country that has suffered more than most from such things."                                                                                                                                        
[8] "This invasion may or may not be benign, but isn't it better to err on the side of caution?"                                                                                                                                                 
[9] "Apparently there are already colonies of Bombus terrestris on Tasmania, so I suppose it is now only a matter of time before they reach the mainland."

#End
```

Using quanteda package, I confirm there are NINE sentences and then to tokenize the text:

```
library(quanteda)
nsentence(text)
# [1] 9

##Searching for word pollination - it finds the first occurrence only

dat <- data.frame(text=sent_detect(text), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Search(dat, "pollination")

[1] "With the recent popularity of using bumblebees in glasshouse  pollination they will probably be found in most parts of the world before long, especially Bombus terrestris which seems to be the most popular species sold for this purpose."


#End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use base R pattern match functions:

```
d <- sent_detect(text)

# grep the sentense with the keyword:
n <- which(grepl('pollination', d) == T)
# 3

# get context of +-1
d[(n - 1):(n + 1)]

# [1] "They range much further north than honey bees, and colonies can be found on Ellesmere Island in northern Canada, only 880 km from the north pole!"
# [2] "With the recent popularity of using bumblebees in glasshouse pollination they will probably be found in most parts of the world before long, especially Bombus terrestris which seems to be the most popular species sold for this purpose."
# [3] "Recently there have been proposals to introduce bumblebees into Australia to pollinate crops in glasshouses."

# nice output:
cat(d[(n - 1):(n + 1)])

# if there are multiple sentences with the keyword:
lapply(which(grepl('pollination', d) == T), function(n){
    cat(d[(n - 1):(n + 1)])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly straight forward way o doing this:

```
dat[c(inds <- grep("[Pp]ollination", dat[[1]]) + 1, inds - 2),]

## [1] "Recently there have been proposals to introduce bumblebees into Australia to pollinate crops in glasshouses."                                     
## [2] "They range much further north than honey bees, and colonies can be found on E
```

llesmere Island in northern Canada, only 880 km from the north pole!"